# How could Rust's channels be implemented?

Tags: multithreading, rust

I'm curious about how could someone implement a send/receive channel in Rust. Certainly some data has to be accessed by 2 threads at the same time. Otherwise, how can thread B know when a mssage from thread A arrived?

In C++, both threads access a shared queue and when one adds to a queue, it notifies a condition variable in where the other thread is waiting.

In Rust I cannot have a shared object: I can move it like it were an C++ unique_ptr, or I can pass a reference to it, but then the object is locked and the other thread can't acces it. Or can it, but only with read permissions? Even if yes, there's still a problem, it might read that variable in the middle of a write.

Comment: Surely you can have something like `Arc<RwLock<SharedObject>>`?

Comment: @PiRocks I've searched about RwLock. So, `RwLock<SomeObject> r` means that lots of threads can read but only one write. But how can this be possible on Rust? If I pass `r` to thread `A`, then how can thread `B` have access to it? I can only borrow it to thread `A` or give ornweship to thread `A`. In both cases thread `B` wouldn't be able to access `r`

Comment: @PiRocks and why `Arc` is needed?

Comment: There is a reasonably good description of how they work in the source here: https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/src/std/sync/mpsc/mod.rs.html#120

Comment: The `Arc` is so that you can many "copys"(actually just references to the same lock) of the RwLock. Additionally you can't really put any constraints on when threads will exit, so you need an Arc to ensure there no leaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For situations like this Rust has `unsafe` code blocks, raw C `*mut` pointers, and `UnsafeCell` wrapper type. These are low-level building blocks for creating higher-level (and safe) abstractions.

`UnsafeCell` informs the compiler that the memory it holds will be mutably shared by threads, and the compiler won't make it Undefined Behavior to mutate it from multiple threads. Then code can add some synchronization primitives around the cell to make it actually safe. This is the key to implementing internals of types like `Atomic`, `Mutex`, and channels.